# Ajax não está retornando json na tabela em html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, json

Estou tentando fazer uma tabela em que o conteudo dela venha de um http. Estou usando Ajax e Json para puxar o conteudo mas não retorna nada na tela além do que está escrito em HTML. Sou iniciante ainda, alguem poderia me dar uma luz?

Na url eu mudei o nome do caminho pois não sei se posso divulga-lo, mas está igual.

Antes de inserir headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'} o console me dava o erro de Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/?_=1551360232378. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  

           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
        <div class="container">

            <table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered" id="gp_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cdgrupo</th>
                    <th>Grupos</th>
                    <th>Inativo</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            </table>

        </div>
        </body>



    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/",
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache:false,
        success: function(data){
            /*console.log(data);*/
            var event_data = '';
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                /*console.log(value);*/
                event_data += '<tr>';
                event_data += '<td>'+value.Cdgrupo+'</td>';
                event_data += '<td>'+value.Grupos+'</td>';
                event_data += '<td>'+value.Inativo+'</td>';
                event_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $("#gp_table").append(event_data);
        },
        error: function(d){
            /*console.log("error");*/
            alert("Não foi carregado.");
        }
    });
});


        </script>



        </html>
```

O Json está assim:

```
[
{
Cdgrupo: 1,
Grupos: "MADEIRA ",
Inativo: 0
},
{
Cdgrupo: 2,
Grupos: "SEGURANCA E EPIS",
Inativo: 0
},
{
Cdgrupo: 3,
Grupos: "INFORMATICAS E ACESSORIOS",
Inativo: 0
}
]
```

EDIT: A partir de uma extensão do chrome eu consegui fazer com que tudo aparecesse certinho, então o codigo está escrito certinho. Só falta resolver o erro que da quando eu tento sem usar a extensão, e por sua vez em outro navegador.

Erro: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/?_=1551360232378. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

Comment: Ainda tenho um conhecimento mto basico, como posso resolver? Puxar de um arquivo local para o que eu estou tentando fazer não resolve.

Comment: A página requisitada em `url:` tem que retornar **apenas** um JSON válido, senão dá erro porque o `dataType: 'json'` vai tentar fazer o parse no retorno e se não for JSON esse retorno irá entrar no erro.

Comment: Coloquei como está o meu JSON, está correto?

Comment: A sintaxe é um objeto JavaScript válido, mas não um JSON válido. JSON é um formato baseado na sintaxe do JavaScript - todo JSON é um objeto válido, mas nem todo objeto é um JSON válido. Em JSON, os nomes dos atributos devem ser declarados entre aspas duplas, `"Cdgrupo"`, `"Grupos"`, `"Cdgrupo"`

Comment: O JSON que eu coloquei está vindo da origem dele, do http. Não tenho como edita-lo. Eu achei que nesse caso seria reconhecido.

Comment: Falta a vírgula após `headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}`... removi a resposta porque o problema parece ser outro e não apenas o da vírgula.

Comment: Esse problema é o que estou tendo agora: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/?_=1551364713192' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o problema possa esta no seu header, tente isso:

`$.ajax({
        url: "http://exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/exemplo/",
        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache:false,
        success: function(data){
            /*console.log(data);*/
            var event_data = '';
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                /*console.log(value);*/
                event_data += '<tr>';
                event_data += '<td>'+value.Cdgrupo+'</td>';
                event_data += '<td>'+value.Grupos+'</td>';
                event_data += '<td>'+value.Inativo+'</td>';
                event_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $("#gp_table").append(event_data);
        },
        error: function(d){
            /*console.log("error");*/
            alert("Não foi carregado.");
        }
    });`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Lucas. Não funcionou.

Comment: Qual foi o erro que retornou?

Comment: Continuou dando o mesmo erro